# static const POD vs const POD

Tags: c++, static, constants

For POD local to a class member function:

Is there any reason to prefer `static const int ONE = 1;` or `const int ONE = 1`?

Is there any reason to prefer `static const float HALF = (float)0.5;` or `const float HALF = (float)0.5`.

e.g. for function `f` in class `A`

```
 #ifdef SP
 #define float REAL
 #else
 #define double REAL
 #endif

double
A::f(const REAL x)
{
   static const REAL HALF = (REAL)0.5;
   return max(x, HALF);
}

or

double
A::f(const REAL x)
{
   const REAL HALF = (REAL)0.5;
   return max(x, HALF);
}

or

double
A::f(const REAL x)
{
   const REAL HALF = 0.5f;
   return max(x, HALF);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside a function/method the plain `const` variable can, for example, be computed from parameters and assigned a different value within corresponding invocations of a function/method, while the `static const` one can be initialized only once (possibly from parameters too), and subsequent invocations simply have no effect on its value. To illustrate this difference, take a look at the following demo:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void
non_static_case(int x, int y) {
   const int z = x + y;

   cout << z << endl;
}

void
static_case(int x, int y) {
   static const int z = x + y;

   cout << z << endl;
}

int
main() {
    non_static_case(1, 2);
    non_static_case(3, 4);

    cout << endl;

    static_case(1, 2);
    static_case(3, 4);
}
```

Output:

```
3
7

3
3
```

You can clearly see that `z` inside the `static_case` function, after being initialized for the 1st time, does not change anymore on subsequent calls.

It is worth mentioning that typically compilers utilize a hidden flag to indicate if the local `static` variable has already been initialized. This flag is checked on every entry to the function, and this results in little overhead. Nevertheless, in this particular case, **when only primitive types are considered and the variable is assigned to a compile-time constant**, I have no doubts that the resulting code gets optimized by compiler and no hidden flag is actually used. As a result, I'd say that there is **no reason to prefer one approach over another**, in this particular case.

In case if the variable is a member of some class, actually the same rules, as for the variable inside function/method case, apply. The `const` member can be computed in the constructor initialization list and is associated with a particular instance of the class, whereas the `static const` one is set during program startup initialization and remains unchanged for the rest of the execution and is *"shared"* among all the instances of the class.

Comment: True, it is clear that the static qualification prevents reassignment. The original question is asking if there is a reason to prefer "static const POD" or "const POD" for variables which are local to a class function which always evaluate to the same value.